# Python Reddit Praw

Tags: python, reddit

I am trying to make code that takes links and a string from reddit and displays them. I took the code [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/46nb99/for_my_first_project_i_made_a_display_that_takes/) but it returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "epst4.py", line 20, in <module>
    with open('/home/pi/project/display.html', 'w') as f:f.write(template.format(imgURL, wittyText))
    IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

And here is my code:

```
import os, praw, random, requests, time

r = praw.Reddit(client_id='abc',client_secret='abc', password = 'abc', user_agent = 'abc',username='abc')
getCount = 25

while True:
    earthpornSub = r.get_subreddit('earthporn')
    showerthoughtSub = r.get_subreddit('showerthoughts')

    earthpornContent = earthpornSub.get_top_from_week(limit = getCount)
    showerthoughtContent = showerthoughtSub.get_top_from_week(limit = getCount)

    earthpornList = [sub for sub in earthpornContent]
    showerthoughtList = [sub for sub in showerthoughtContent]

    imgURL = earthpornList[random.randint(0, getCount - 1)].url
    wittyText = showerthoughtList[random.randint(0, getCount - 1)].title  # They're typically supposed to be all in the title

    with open('/home/pi/project/template.html', 'r') as f: template = f.read()
    with open('/home/pi/project/display.html', 'a') as f: f.write(template.format(imgURL, wittyText))

    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: missing an apostrophe on line 19 `/home/pi/project/template.html'`

Comment: Thanks. I'll make the edit! However, even when I add that it is the same issue.

Comment: does your template.html refer only to {0} and {1} or also to a missing {2} ?

Comment: We need to see the source of `template.html` and `display.html` as well.